# Ubuntu 16.04 - XBOX360 USB controller detected, but not listed as joystick

Tags: drivers, usb, games, input, joystick

So I'm a pretty fresh Linux user, and as I'm going to travel a bit soon I really wanted to use my wired XBOX 360 controller to play some games on my laptop, but I've been unable to make it work, so I used this [guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/ubuntu-xbox-controller-support-xboxdrv-driver) to install xboxdrv, though this didn't fix it. Whenever I open the joystick tab in the settings the only controllers listed are four non existent wireless controllers.

I tried running the `lsusb` command, and this is the result I get from it:

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b270 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bb4:0f25 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) One M8
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e1 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable SoftSailing
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And as you can see the device is listed for bus 8, so the system knows that the controller is connected. By using `sudo xboxdrv --silent` i get the following message:

```
xboxdrv 0.8.5 - http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/ 
Copyright © 2008-2011 Ingo Ruhnke <grumbel@gmx.de> 
Licensed under GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> 
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. 
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain 
conditions; see the file COPYING for details. 

Controller:        Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller
Vendor/Product:    045e:028e
USB Path:          008:002
Controller Type:   Xbox360

-- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------
 Error couldn't claim the USB interface: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY
Try to run 'rmmod xpad' and then xboxdrv again or start xboxdrv with the option --detach-kernel-driver.
```

Using `rrmod xpad` yields nothing as the program isn't installed, `evtest` only displays the four non existent wireless controllers. So I'm a bit confused about what I can do to solve the problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a HP ProBook 6475b (A3Z20AV).

EDIT: I've been looking around and can't seem to find any info about using gamepads with ubuntu 16.04. The xboxdrv program I tried only goes up to 15.04, so I'm not sure if that might be why it's not working?

Comment: Have you tried what it suggests at the end of the error message? And have you rebooted?

Comment: Yeah, tried both rebooting and using `rmmod xpad` and the `--detach-kernel-driver` option, though that didn't really help, and the error message says that `USBController::USBController(): libusb_open() failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS` so I'm not sure if the LIBUSB error might be crucial to solving this

Comment: I got it working by using `sudo rmmod xpad`

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the driver

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge xboxdrv xboxdrv:i386
   ```
2. Use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove non needed packages
3. Get this one which seems to be working for me:

   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/i386/xboxdrv/0.8.5-1